# Robot Framework - Execute tests on multiple environments in parallel

Tags: robotframework

I got a projet that running on multiple environnement en production. So I got an identical test environment like the production.

I need to execute my RobotFramework tests on each of this test environnement, in parralel.
So my needs is to do these 3 task in parralel with only 1 execution, in parallel to not waste time..

`robot -d rapport -v env:UAT1 tests/`

`robot -d rapport -v env:UAT2 tests/`

`robot -d rapport -v env:UAT3 tests/`

I tried to use --argumentfile to do it, in each of them I added env:UAT1, env:UAT2, env:UAT3. It should execute the tests for each argumentfile but it doesnt work :

`robot -d rapport --argumentfile UAT1.args --argumentfile UAT2.args --argumentfile UAT3.args tests/`

I tried pabot but it doesnt seems to work too...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the suite initialization file, to set your environment variables, and you can trigger it using a CMD variable.